# Referencing a java list always returns the last element

Tags: java, list

I'm stumped and need another pair of eyes to look at this. This code was working and suddenly stopped working. Basically I'm adding an object to an arraylist. when I'm building the list I watch it and it seems to add a unique object each iteration. Basically a sprite that will appear on the screen and its x, y coordinates, color, and speed. Earlier this worked and the sprites would appear scattered on screen, now it seems to duplicate the very last object added to the list, X number of times I run the loop I end up with the same object. which doesn't make any sense...

The first println statements prints whats being passed to the constructor. So it prints out as so.

Ball: 1 x: 123 y:344 Color: Blue
Ball: 2 x: 3 y 233 Color: Green
Ball 3 x: 24 y: 3 Color: Blue

Everything looks great so far. Then I actually print the list to console and I get

Ball: 1 x: 24 y: 3 Color: Blue
Ball: 1 x: 24 y: 3 Color: Blue
Ball: 1 x: 24 y: 3 Color: Blue

Which here in lies the problem I'm trying to figure out why that is happening...

```
  //When I create the List Eclipse refused to accept it until I initialized it like so...

  java.util.List <Sprite> sprite = new java.util.ArrayList<Sprite>();    
  //yes I did import java.util.*; Eclipse still was digging it. This was working correctly despite the way i added it. I also changed this to a Vector which Eclispe was more content with with no effect. 

  private void GenerateSprites(){
        //Random to keep it random
        Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        //variables for selecting and setting color
        Color color = null;
    int colorValue;
    //variables for their x,y coordinates
    float bX = 0;
    float bY = 0;
    //Create each ball set the color and generate the x,y coordinates
    for (int x = 0; x < NUM_BALLS; x++){
        colorValue = r.nextInt(4);
        if (colorValue == 0) color = Color.BLUE;
        if (colorValue == 1) color = Color.RED;
        if (colorValue == 2) color = Color.YELLOW;
        if (colorValue == 3) color = Color.GREEN;

        bX = r.nextInt((int)(gameField.getWidth() - gameField.getWidth() / 4)+SCRN_MARGIN);
        bY = r.nextInt((int)(gameField.getHeight() - gameField.getHeight() / 4)+SCRN_MARGIN);

        //place the new ball in the gameField
   //print the values being passed to the sprite constrcutor for debug purposes. The out put of this line indicates that all is well at this point.             
System.out.println("Ball: " + x + " X: " + bX+ " Y: " + (bY+SCRN_MARGIN) + " Color: " + color.toString());
        gSprite.add(new Sprite((float)bX, (float)bY+SCRN_MARGIN, BALL_SIZE, color));

    }
    //Now that the sprites are added to this list print out the list.   When this line executes it shows a list of NUM_BALLS all of which have the exact sdame vlaues as the last sprite added earlier. 
    for (int x = 0; x < gSprite.size(); x++){
        Sprite spr = gSprite.get(x);

  System.out.println("Ball: " + x + " X: " + spr.getX()+ " Y: " + spr.getY() + " vX: " + spr.getvX() + " vY: " + spr.getvY() + " Color: " + spr.getColor().toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: "This code was working and suddenly stopped working"... what have you changed? Code never *stops* working magically.

Comment: If there is an exception please add the stack trace...

Comment: What is printed to the console whenever you run this code?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is the size of the array what you expect it to be?

Why not return an array of sprites from this function as opposed to overwriting a global variable? That's my first recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

```
bX = r.nextInt((int)(gameField.getWidth() - gameField.getWidth() / 4)+SCRN_MARGIN);
```

You are trying to assign an integer to float. Please check this, May be that is creating problem because of rounding up of numbers

Comment: I went throuigh and checkerd this code and the castings are all correct now. Still didn'

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the  `hashcode` and `equals` implementation of your `Sprite` class. They need to consider the relevant fields of `Sprite`so two different ones don't return the same hashcode or return true for equals. I think it works if you're using the default implementation (e.g. not overriding it), but implement one to be sure. In eclipse you can choose `Source` → `Generate hashCode() and equals()`. This should not matter though if you're really using `ArrayList` (I don't see that in your code).

I agree with @Sanket that it may be a problem of converting a floating point number to integer. Maybe it just looks like you're getting the same one every time?

Also, you should use the `enhanced for-loop` of Java 5. The second loop could be rewritten like this (and may even work as expected then...):

```
int x = 0;
for (Sprite spr : gSprite){
    System.out.println("Ball: " + x + " X: " + spr.getX()+ " Y: " + spr.getY() + " vX: " + spr.getvX() + " vY: " + spr.getvY() + " Color: " + spr.getColor().toString());
    x++;
}
```

And, last but not least, you should really use `switch/case` instead of the four ifs. This actually won't help your problem but it's just bad style. Take a look:

```
switch (colorValue) {
        case 0:
            color = Color.BLUE;
            break;
        case 1:
            color = Color.RED;
            break;
        case 2:
            color = Color.YELLOW;
            break;
        case 3:
            color = Color.GREEN;
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected color!");
}
```

Btw: There are other approaches like using `Enum` or a `Map` for this kind of pattern. I just think having more than 2 ifs for one logic-bit merits using `switch/case`. Of course, the default case is handled poorly and would need refinement.

Oh and one more thing: You should really write method names lowercase/camel case. Basically every Java programmer excepts it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the Advice I normally do follow those standards this is rather rough code, I've been converting to something more final. The problem basically is the items this method is adding to the list sprite. It adds five sprites to this list and they all seem to be unique, but when I access the list later on they all have the values of the last sprite added to the list... I wrote this post because it was working before and I know I did something to upset it along the way but I can't figure Out what I did. I probably should have  made a copy of it before I started messing with it.