# When reading from a java util List, why do all elements return the last element? (generalized)

Tags: java, list

**Question:**     Why does the following print out:

```
ChildB___Parent of ChildB
ChildB___Parent of ChildB
```

Instead of what I think it should print out:

```
ChildA___Parent of ChildA
ChildB___Parent of ChildB
```

Short Self Contained Generalized Example of Issue:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StackExchangeQuestion1 {
public static void main(String[] args){
   List<String[]> list = new ArrayList();   
   String[] pair = {"childID","parentID"}; //for readability this gets overwritten       

//adding values to list
   pair[0] = "ChildA";
   pair[1] = "Parent of ChildA";
   list.add(pair);

   pair[0] = "ChildB";
   pair[1] = "Parent of ChildB";
   list.add(pair);

//checking values in list
   for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
   pair = list.get(i); //variable reuse for readability
   System.out.println(pair[0]+"___"+pair[1]);
   }
}}//end class and main
```

Comment: Note: I searched for previous answers this is a duplicate of at least 2
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509335/referencing-a-java-list-always-returns-the-last-element
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324754/why-all-elements-of-my-list-seems-to-be-the-same
---
I've made a new question, because those were not Short Self Contained Generic Examples of the problem/question they had, and were not reader friendly. (the code did 10 things, but the question only involved 1 thing) I also didn't want to hijack their questions with my own.

Comment: I've tried replacing for loop contents with:       System.out.println(list.get(i)[0]+"___"+list.get(i)[1]);              I've also tried just using arraylist, neither worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the same `String[]` reference twice to your list.  Because of this, both elements in your list point to the same object.  So, when you overwrote your array, you were really writing to the same piece of memory.  The list was referencing this piece of memory twice, so you get 2 identical print statements.

Java will pass all non-primitive values by reference (that means it will pass a pointer to where a non-primitive object is stored in memory.)

If you were storing integers instead like so:

```
int a = 10;
list.add(a);
a = 20;
list.add(a);
```

Everything would be fine, because `a` is an interger, integers are primtive values, and  primitive values are passed **by value.**  This means the data is stored in a is copied to the list, not the point in memory `a` is held at.

Strings and arrays of any sort, however, are non-primitive.

To fix your code then, you need to pass 2 separate references to your list:

```
String[] pair1 = {"ChildA","Parent of ChildA"};
String[] pare2 = {"ChildB", "Parent of ChildB"};
//adding values to list
list.add(pair1);
list.add(pair2);
```

Edit:

You'd expressed concerns in comments about verbosity.  First, I think your code isn't verbose.  But if you're truly concerned about it here's a way to shorten it:

```
list.add(new String[]{"ChildA","Parent of ChildA"});
list.add(new String[]{"ChildB","Parent of ChildB"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, I figured I was missing some fundamental.

Comment: How could I make java pass a non-primitive value by value? so I can have less verbose code. ----Or is this just wrong, and I should be using a method to create a new ArrayList object, that has the values I want in it, for less verbose code.

Comment: This isn't wrong- its an approach I use at my job sometimes. You'd have to perform what's called a shallow copy.  You create a new reference, and fill it up with the data inside your old reference. In this case, you'd create a new array, and fill it with the contents of the previous. However this will make your code more verbose, not less. I don't feel your code is verbose here however. Verbose code is declaring too many temporary variables or excessive comments imho.  You are doing neither.  I think you are fine.

Comment: Thanks to everyone filling in missing background knowledge, I figured out a solution that fits my coding style. Basically code version of what you all are saying to do.     `private static String[] newPair (String a, String b){            String[] pair = {a,b};                                       return pair;  }                        list.add(newPair("ChildA","Parent of ChildA")); list.add(newPair("ChildB","Parent of ChildB"));`

Comment: o sweet that's just what I was looking for, far better than a method, thanks so much!, I'll upvote your answer as soon as I hit 15 rep lol. Before reading your answer, I didn't know the syntax at the bottom of your answer was possible :)

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.  May I suggest another thing?  Instead of passing string arrays into your list, why not create a class which holds 2 strings instead? It will make your code more readable, and more flexible. This is fine if what you're writing is a simple routine in a big project, but if you're doing something important here, a class might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Because an `ArrayList` stores *references*, not *objects*.  The reference `pair` always refers to the same object; you're simply adding that reference to your list twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your string object array is overriding here. Your last change only will reflect in your string because list will store object's reference. If you want to get your assumed output create new objects every time before you set value.